# architecture issue on compiling unit test using GHUnit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5, gh-unit

Am using Xcode 4.5.

Recently i have download GHunit framework and setup it by following [link](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_install_ios_4.html).

On compiling the target, am getting the error mentioned below. need your valuable suggestion.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_CACurrentMediaTime", referenced from:
          _GHRunForInterval in GHUnitIOS(GHTestUtils.o)
          _GHRunUntilTimeoutWhileBlock in GHUnitIOS(GHTestUtils.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 24):

`CACurrentMediaTime` is declared at `CABase.h` and implemented at `QuartzCore` framework, you'll need to link it to the project.

Comment: @yokks Please uncheck the answer if it doesn't solve the problem, if you found another solution you are always welcome to answer yourself and accept it instead.

Comment: And for the persone down-voted the answer, here's the GHUnit source file from the (currently) latest version tag, there you can see import of the QuartzCore header: https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/blob/0.5.6/Classes-iOS/GHUnitIOSTestView.m

Comment: You are correct. The error is due to QuartzCore framework not linked. Let me up vote for you.

Comment: @yokks could you try updating GHunit to the latest version and check if this solution works for you ? It seems to be helpful for other users, let's try to find out what is different for you.

Answer (score 1):

In our mobile application development course at school, we have been using this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-tutorial-for-ios-xcode-4-quick-start-guide

And It does not Run without the QuartzCore.framework as well, so thank you very much !